# Unable to Update MySQL row after successful Paypal Payment

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I have successfully set up the Paypal button and can receive email from my IPN code. However, I am not sure how to know which user actually made the payment. My doubt is that The email address used by user may not be the same as the one used to signup from my service. I tried to grab username from `$_SESSION`  but it returns empty string. Here is my code:

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$body = $txn_id.' '.$payment_amount.' '.$payment_status.' '.$payment_time.' '.$username;
mail("Email Address", 'Subject', $body, ''); 
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
$query       = $connection->query("UPDATE members SET TRANSID = '$txn_id', PAYAMOUNT = '$payment_amount', PAYSTATUS = '$payment_status', PAYTIME =     '$payment_time' WHERE USERNAME ='$username'");
mysqli_close($connection);
```

I have also added `session_start();` at the beginning of `ipn.php`. What should I do to update data for correct user.

**UPDATE**

I am using Paypal IPN system. A user can pay with Paypal on the upgrade page. Then Paypal sends me transaction details on ipn.php. Now, I am writing code in ipn.php to update the MySQL table.

**UPDATE TWO**

After suggestion from steammike this is what I have.

Now my code looks like this:

```
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$username = $_POST['fuser'];
```

and my button like this:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ATXN4EP7FQXR8">
<input type="hidden" name="fuser" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pay With Paypal" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

The `$username` variable is still blank though.

**UPDATE 3**

I am still unable to update the Table after changing `fuser` to `custom` in button like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>">
```

and form like this:

```
$username = $_POST["custom"];
```

The only thing that gets updated is 'PAYTIME'. Although in the email I receive all the data. This is the structure of table:

```
TRANSID     varchar(20)
PAYAMOUNT   decimal(7,2)
PAYSTATUS   varchar(25)
PAYTIME     datetime
```

Comment: where you set this session and where your session_start?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy Did you mean where did I set `$_SESSION['user']`? I set it up after a user has logged in or from remember me option and session start is a the top of every web page in `header.php`.

Comment: if you put session_start(); before this line $username = $_SESSION['user']; -- what is happening?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy I may have not been able to clearly state my issue. It is similar to the question that Steammike linked to in answer.

Comment: use "custom" as a input name and check it once.